# Android: Error en requestAudioFocus()

Tags: java, android

Cree esta clase para reproducir un archivo de sonido en android: https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/c8c57e1b67b9a1152e82b8a93629f9c5

El problema es que al correr esta aplicación en mi celular esta se detiene al instante. Al revisar el logcat aparece [este](https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/dc9feac1a3a0107095f6bdadf4a678dc) error.

Usando el debuger de android studio pude rastrear el error a la línea 52:

```
int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager .STREAM_MUSIC,
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

Investigue la función requestAudioFocus e intente aplicarla como dice la [documentación de google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) así que modifique la actividad para que coincidiera con la documentación: https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/fd32902a9dc663580de343de0f1454d7

Ahora el error se produce en la línea 58:

```
AudioAttributes playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build();
```

**Nota:** Android studio mostraba el error "*Call requires API level 26 (current min is 15)*" así que tuve que añadir "*@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)*" en la línea 50.

En el logcat aparece el [este](https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/6091691e316fb297d1416873fb879be1) error al correr esta versión de la actividad.

La pregunta es: **¿Cuál es la manera correcta de utilizar la función requestAudioFocus()?**

**Nota:** La versión de Android del celular que estoy usando para testear la aplicación es 4.2.2 y según la [documentación de google](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) el nivel de API que utiliza es 17 (JELLY_BEAN_MR1)

**Nota 2:** La app esta "inspirada" de [este](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/lesson-four) repositorio. En caso de que quieran correr esta aplicación deberán modificar el archivo [build.gradle](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/blob/lesson-four/build.gradle) y agregar la función "*google()*" en la línea 18.

Comment: Por qué en la línea 42 intentas reproducir un audio que aparentemente es un color? Hablo de `R.raw.color_red`

Comment: El audio reproduce literalmente la palabra red. Se supone que cuando el usuario toca un botón en la aplicación asociado con un color se reproduce ese color. Es un error con el nombre del archivo, probablemente el archivo debería haberse llamado audio_red.

Comment: El error que te da es porque no encuentra la clase, lo cual puede ser que no la has importado (cosa extraña porque android studio lo suele hacer automaticamente) o porque la api que estás usando es inferior a otra en la que sí que esta la clase, que version estás usando?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sobre el error que se produjo mientras implementabas [este codigo](https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/c8c57e1b67b9a1152e82b8a93629f9c5):

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Se produjo porque no se inicializo `mAudioManager` para utilizar el metodo `.requestAudioFocus`.

Debes inicializarlo a `mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);` razon por la cual en el [codigo actualizado](https://gist.github.com/MahaSaka/fd32902a9dc663580de343de0f1454d7) ya no explota en esa parte.

Sobre el error en el codigo:

```
AudioAttributes playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build();
```

[AudioAttributes](http://segun%20la%20[documentaci%C3%B3n%20oficial][3]) solo debe ser utilizado en versiones con un min sdk marcado en `API >= 21` . Por lo que si intentas correr ese bloque de código en una versión inferior, te causara la excepción:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.media.AudioAttributes$Builder"

La solucion aqui es implementar ambas formas marcando el codigo en una version o el metodo con el annotation @RequiresApi.

Por ejemplo, asi debes llamar para reproducir el audio para las diferentes versiones:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
{
    // Aqui debes hacerlo con AudioAttributes
    PlayAudioWithAttributes(R.raw.color_red);
} 
else
{
    // Aqui tienes que hacerlo de la otra forma, sin audio Attributes
    PlayAudioWithoutAttributes(R.raw.color_red);
}

// Para versiones API 21+
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void PlayAudioWithAttributes(int audioResourceID) {

    //Create and setup the media player for the audio resource.
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioResourceID);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    AudioAttributes playbackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build();

    AudioFocusRequest focusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
            .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes)
            .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
            .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener)
            .build();

    //Request audio focus in order to play an audio file. The app needs to play a short audio file
    //so we will request AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT
    int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusRequest);

    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        //Start the audio file
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void PlayAudioWithoutAttributes(int audioResourceID) {
   // Aqui debes poner el codigo de como se hacia antes
}
```

Para la version vieja `(API < 21)` es decir el metodo `PlayAudioWithoutAttributes`, puedes revisar [este codigo](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kuccello/5816882/raw/d552ad2951b201f901d55ca41426cbc10fe59424/MusicPlayer.java), que es la forma correcta de implementarlo. Segun la documentación, luego de hacer el request del audio focus, debes abandonarlo. Ten en cuenta, que ese codigo utiliza un BroadcastReceiver, por lo que solo te interesaría la parte relacionada con el `requestAudioFocus` y obviamente descartaras todo el código que guarda relación con el Broadcast. Buena suerte.